# How to properly use std::shared_from_this or trick around it?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Question for C++ experts: I've got a library function expecting a `shared_ptr<T>` and I'd like to call this function within `T`. I know [`share_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) is the correct way to go, but I can't get my head around it (and how to use it properly).

I've come up with a trick and I'd like to know if its safe (no UB). If it's not, could you explain me how to use `share_from_this` in my case?

```
#include <memory>

template<class T>
void library_function(std::shared_ptr<T>)
{}

struct A {
    std::shared_ptr<A> share()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<A>(this, [](A*){});
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        library_function(share());
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a();
}
```

Comment: In this code, it's safe. If `library_function` stores that `shared_ptr` to use later and `a` is destroyed. It's UB

Comment: It is not so difficult in general - just inherit from enable_shared_from_this, then you get a member function shared_from_this that can produce shared ptrs without duplicates or destroying refcount of the shared_ptr that owns an A.

Comment: @Danh You're the only one to address my question (about whiether it's safe or not). You could turn your comment into an answer and get the rep from it.

Comment: *"I know share_from_this is the correct way to go"*. It is mostly a work-around. The way to go is to have the `shared_ptr<A>` available.

Comment: @Jarod42 The thing is, I'd like `A` to call `library_function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, it's safe.

However, if `library_function` stores that `shared_ptr` to use later and `a` is destroyed because of out of scope. It's undefined behavior. It's not safe then. This sample code is not much different from your code but it has undefined behavior in the second call:

```
template<class T>
void library_function(std::shared_ptr<T> t)
{
    static std::shared_ptr<T> s;
    if (!s) {
        s = t;
    }
    if (s) s->do_something();
}

struct A {
    std::shared_ptr<A> share()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<A>(this, [](A*){});
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        library_function(share());
    }
    void do_something() {
    }
};


int main()
{
    // This emulates some function call and go out of scope
    {
        A a;
        a();
    }
    // This call is undefined behavior
    library_function(std::shared_ptr<A>{});
}
```

The right way to do it is something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YbNjJ75TEAwV4XBb):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void library_function(std::shared_ptr<T> t)
{
    static std::shared_ptr<T> s;
    if (!s) {
        s = t;
    }
    if (s) s->do_something();
}

struct A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    ~A() {std::cout << "Destructed\n"; }
    std::shared_ptr<A> share()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        library_function(share());
    }
    void do_something() {
        std::cout << "do_something\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    // This emulates some function call and go out of scope
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
        (*a)();
    }
    library_function(std::shared_ptr<A>{});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all , the object you want to `share_from_this` needs to be previously shared object and managed by std::shared_ptr. Ensuring that, classes that allow it need publicly inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`. Next, if you want to create shared pointer from this you need to use method `shared_from_this()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should derive your class from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Make sure your object is managed by a `std::shared_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>

template<class T>
void library_function(std::shared_ptr<T>)
{}

struct A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {

    void operator()()
    {
        library_function(shared_from_this());
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->operator()();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`, then you can call `this->shared_from_this()` to get a `shared_ptr<>` to it.

For example:

```
class foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<foo> {
public:
   void bar() {
      call_some_func(this->shared_from_this());
   }
};
```

So `call_some_func()` will receive a shared pointer to the `foo` instance. This will work as the original instance is already in a shared pointer, i.e. the instance is created as:

```
auto foo_inst = std::make_shared<foo>();
```